# How to define a getter function

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing a library which allows to build Bayesian nets. The structure of a net is encapsulated and the user cannot access its fields; however they can get and set some of them. Say you want to write the accessor function for the field `table` (which is basically a double array) for instance. Between the following options, which would be more appropriate?

First option:

```
int getTable(Net *net, double *res)
```

Second option:

```
double *getTable(Net *net)
```

In the first option, the user provides a pointer to the array where the table values will be written. The function copies the table values on `res`, leaving the user with no direct access to the internal structure. Modifying `res` leaves the table of the net unchanged. Of course, another function (say `getTableSize()`) is provided to correctly allocate `res`. This seems safe (the internal structure stay coherent) and has the advantage that you can return a code value if something goes wrong. The downside is that this approach can be slower than the next one, since it involves a copy. Typically, the number of values of `table` may vary from just 1 to a couple of hundreds.

In the second option, the function returns directly the pointer to the internal values. In the doc, I will specify that user cannot try to free the pointer or modify the values. Freeing the pointer would likely result in a segmentation fault and memory leaks if other operations on the net are performed. Modifying the table won't result in any apparent error, but the internal coherence would be broken and the results of subsequent calculations might be very wrong and very hard to debug for the user.

Which option do you prefer? There other stuff to consider? Is there another approach to prefer?

Comment: I would take the former approach. The user of this library might have his preferences about dynamic memory allocation (like not using it at all..).

Comment: IMO both approaches have their place based on required semantics. the first approach has the merit of being safe due to not exposing the internals, but the second approach would be beneficial for say, a pop function for a container data structer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would go for the first option because of the ability to return an error code. This would also solve your problem regarding the user freeing wrongly the returned value. And passing a pointer on a variable declared on the stack is easy.

Note that you can also make things more clear, i.e. the returned value cannot be modified or freed, with the second option by returning a const pointer like this

```
const double * getTable(Net *net);
```

In such way, the caller cannot modify the value, unless he cast it to a non const but I think this would be going a bit too far since the caller break intentionally your interface.

More info on constness can be found [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const_%28computer_programming%29)

Comment: Good point about the `const` qualifier. I adopted the first approach for the reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good habit is to always demand a return code from functions that can fail for some reason.

Error handling is much more efficient when working with return codes.

I'd go with option one.

Also, I don't know if this is a mistake or not but option two returns a double pointer - if this is the correct behavior, then function one should have the signature:

```
int getTable(Net *net, double **res)
```

Additionally, as Eugene Sh. mentioned in the comments, some environments might not even support malloc (some embedded devices firmware comes to mind), so giving the user a choice whether to pass in a malloc'd variable or a stack allocated variable is also a good selling point for option one.

Comment: No mistake. The `table` field is just a `double` array. The `res` argument is a pointer to an array which will be filled with the proper values. A typical usage is `double res[getTableSize(net)]` (or `double *res = malloc(sizeof(double)*getTableSize(net))`) followed by `getTable(net,res)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have two points for you to consider:

1. *You want memory deallocation to be in the same place where allocation is.* If you allocate memory in a function and return pointer to it, then the caller of the function has to know how to free it and has to remember to free it. Maintaining that kind of code would be a nightmare.
2. *Premature optimization is the root of all evil.* Do not optimize your code until you are certain (i.e. you measured) that exactly that part of code is causing problems.

That said, first option is the only option.

Comment: Agree with both points. Just to be clear, the second method _does not_ allocate any memory, since that memory is already there. It just returns the pointer to it. A `deleteNet()` function is provided which frees all the memory associated to a net.